# How to open application in Xcode 3.2.5, when xcode 4.0.2 is installed?

Tags: iphone

I have installed both xcode 3.2.5 and xcode 4.2. I want to open my application in xcode 3.2.5. How do i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open xcode 3.2.5 (from wherever you have it installed) and just... File > Open?...

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the xcodeproj file and select the desired version

Answer (score 0):

I removed 3.2.5 when installing 4, I had to specify a new location for 4 so could run both side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Just Keep both version of your xcode in dock... Drag and drop the project file to xcode application(version you want) in dock.